# Upper limit on number of redis streams consumer groups?

Tags: redis, redis-streams

We are looking at using redis streams as a cluster wide messaging bus, where each node in the cluster has a unique id.  The idea is that each node, when spawned, creates a consumer group with that unique id to a central redis stream to guarantee each node in the cluster gets a copy of every message.  In an orchestrated environment, cluster nodes will be spawned and removed on the fly, each having a unique id.  Over time I can see this resulting in there being 100's or even 1000's of old/unused consumer groups all subscribed to the same redis stream.

My question is this - is there an upper limit to the number of consumer groups that redis can handle and does a large number of (unused) consumer groups have any real processing cost?  It seems that a consumer group is just a pointer stored in redis that points to the last read entry in the stream, and is only accessed when a consumer of the group does a ranged XREADGROUP.  That would lead me to assume (without diving into Redis code) that the number of consumer groups really does not matter, save for the small amount of RAM that the consumer groups pointers would eat up.

Now, I understand we should be smarter and a node should delete its own consumer groups when it is being killed or we should be cleaning this up on a scheduled basis, but if a consumer group is just a record in redis, I am not sure it is worth the effort - at least at the MVP stage of development.

**TL;DR;**
Is my understanding correct, that there is no practical limit on the number of consumer groups for a given stream and that they have no processing cost unless used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, there's no practical limit to the number of CGs and these do not impact the operational performance.

That said, other than the wasted RAM (which could become significant, depending on the number of consumers in the group and PEL entries), this will add time complexity to invocations of `XINFO STREAM ... FULL` and `XINFO GROUPS` as these list the CGs. Once you have a non-trivial number of CGs, every call to these would become slow (and block the server while it is executing).

Therefore, I'd still recommend implementing some type of "garbage collection" for the "stale" CGs, perhaps as soon as the MVP is done. Like any computing resource (e.g. disk space, network, mutexes...) and given there are no free lunches, CGs need to be managed as well.

P.S. IIUC, you're planning to use a single consumer in each group, and have each CG/consumer correspond to a node in your app's cluster. If that is the case, I'm not sure that you need CGs and you can use the simpler `XREAD` (instead of `XREADGROUP`) while keeping the last ID locally in the node.

OTOH, assuming I'm missing something and that there's a real need for this use pattern, I'd imagine Redis being able to support it better by offering some form of expiry for idle groups.